# Cannot store and access data from Axios.get in React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, axios

As a new user to React, I am trying out a Weather app. My problem is that data is received, but storing and retrieving it. If I store only a few of the values in the data, its working, storing whole object or arrays of arrays don't work. I want to store all data. I don't what is causing the issue.

The code is,

```
import './Weather.css'
import axios from "axios";
import { useEffect, useMemo, useState } from "react";

const Weather=()=>{
  let bg={background:"url('./images/Weather/sky-sunny.jpg')"}
  let [status, setStatus]=useState([])

  let today=new Date;
  let HourTime=today.getHours()
  let hourTime=(HourTime<13)?(HourTime+" am"):(HourTime-12 +" pm")

  if(HourTime<6 && HourTime>18){
    bg={background:"url('./images/Weather/sky-clear-night.jpg')"}
  }
  
  useEffect(()=>{
    axios.get("https://api.open-meteo.com/v1/forecast?latitude=13.04&longitude=80.23&hourly=temperature_2m,relativehumidity_2m,windspeed_10m")
    .then(res=>setStatus([res.data.hourly.windspeed_10m,
        res.data.hourly.temperature_2m,
        res.data.hourly.relativehumidity_2m]))
    },[])

  return(
    <div className="weatherApp">
      <div className='sky' style={bg}>
        <div className='temperature'>
          <span><h1>{status[1][HourTime]}</h1><h3><sup>o</sup>C</h3></span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
export default Weather;
```

In the above code, I am trying to store 3 arrays from the API data, but I am getting

> "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined"

But if I use the below code in useEffect, there is no problem.

```
useEffect(()=>{
  axios.get("https://api.open-meteo.com/v1/forecast?latitude=13.04&longitude=80.23&hourly=temperature_2m,relativehumidity_2m,windspeed_10m")
    .then(res => setStatus([res.data.hourly.windspeed_10m[0],
      res.data.hourly.temperature_2m[0],
      res.data.hourly.relativehumidity_2m[0]])
    )
},[])
```

I want to store more than 1 value from each array. Does this need a better implementation?

Comment: `status[1]` is undefined on the initial render, so `status[1].HourTime` will throw error. Can you clarify what data you want to store, and reconcile that with what you are actually trying to render? The UI doesn't look like it's ready to render arrays of data. What is the value of `res` in the response and what from it do you really want to render?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initially `status` is an empty array. You need to check the length of the array to know whether it is populated by the API call.

Instead of

```
{status[1][HourTime]}
```

try like below

```
{status.length >= 2 && status[1][HourTime]}
```

[image: Edit tender-wildflower-ngbime]

Answer (score 1):

On initial render `status` is empty cause `status[1]` is **undefined** thus you need to check:

```js
{status[1] && status[1][HourTime]}
```

> Does this need a better implementation?

You can move api function outside of **useEffect** like this

```
const WEATHER_API =
  'https://api.open-meteo.com/v1/forecast?latitude=13.04&longitude=80.23&hourly=temperature_2m,relativehumidity_2m,windspeed_10m';

// useCallback to avoid updating on every re-render
const getWeather = React.useCallback(async () => {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get(WEATHER_API);
    setStatus([
      response.data.hourly.windspeed_10m,
      response.data.hourly.temperature_2m,
      response.data.hourly.relativehumidity_2m,
    ]);
  } catch (error) {
    // handle error
  }
}, []);

React.useEffect(() => {
  getWeather();
}, [getWeather]);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Working good. I never used this syntax, great to learn new things.